# Minimal Detectable Change for population surveys

Tags: reliability, group-differences

I am wondering if it would be possible to calculate the Minimal Detectable Change when examining 2 population surveys?

I know how to calculate the MDC in a test-retest situation in which every participant has two measurements (MDC = Standard Error of Measurement X 1.96 X √2 & SEM= square root of the mean square error term from the repeated measures ANOVA). But what if you measure a population at time X and a population at time Y to examine if a certain outcome changed in time, but both populations may not necessarily consist of exactly the same people..So it is not exactly test-retest on a personal level?

Any thoughts on this?